# Moving incorrect values into the right column using R

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a column called Brand_ID where the ID's are supposed to range from 0-6 but there are User_ID numbers that were incorrectly recorded in my Brand_ID column. I've been having trouble finding a way to move these numbers to the right column.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

```
                Brand_ID             User_ID
1060                   0 1515915625212799232
1061                   1 1515915625193362688
1062                   0 1515915625193362688
1063 1515915625216376320                  NA
1064 1515915625216376320                  NA
1065 1515915625216376320                  NA
1066 1515915625216376320                  NA
1067                   1 1313987370474800128
1068                   0 1313987370474800128
1069                   0 1515915625193362688
1070                   0 1515915625061714688
```

```
df <- data.frame(
  Brand_ID = c(
    0, 1, 0, 1515915625216376320, 1515915625216376320, 1515915625216376320,
    1515915625216376320, 1, 0, 0, 0
  ),
  User_ID = c(
    1515915625212799488, 1515915625193362432, 1515915625193362432, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    1313987370474800128, 1313987370474800128, 1515915625193362432,
    1515915625061714432
  )
)
```

I have tried the following code to just check that I am able to loop through the Brand_ID column for the User_ID values in it, but nothing is printing. I have also tried using return and paste instead of print, but with no success.

I haven't gotten to the point in trying to actually switch the values, but I am also lost on how to do that as well.

any help is appreciated!

```
 brand <- !is.na(j$Brand_ID)
> for (x in 1:length(brand)){
+   if (brand[x] > 6)
+     {print(x)}
+   else
+     {next}
+ }
```

Comment: If the 4 values for `Brand_ID` are moved to replace the NA values in `User_ID`, what value should replace the moved `Brand_ID` values? Do they become NA?

Comment: I would also check whether the issue lies with the data, or how it was read into R - do the columns in the raw data file have the same issue?

Comment: @neilfws Hi! yes the original data file has the same issue and the values in Brand_ID can become NA.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.
I was getting scientific notation as well, therefore options(scipen = 999).

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(dplyr)
brand_fixed <- brand %>%
  mutate(User_ID = case_when(Brand_ID > 6 ~ Brand_ID,
                             Brand_ID <= 6 ~ User_ID)) %>%
           mutate(Brand_ID = case_when(Brand_ID > 6 ~ NA,
                                       Brand_ID <= 6 ~ Brand_ID))
```

The idea is mutate overwrites each column by using a case_when to evaluate whether to insert the current value of Brand_ID  or to use the User_ID already there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

another base R approach, `d` being your original data:

```
    z <- is.na(d$User_ID)
    d[z, ] <- d[z, c('User_ID', 'Brand_ID')]
```

```
    ## > d
    ##      Brand_ID      User_ID
    ## 1060        0 1.515916e+18
    ## 1061        1 1.515916e+18
    ## 1062        0 1.515916e+18
    ## 1063       NA 1.515916e+18
    ## 1064       NA 1.515916e+18
    ## 1065       NA 1.515916e+18
    ## 1066       NA 1.515916e+18
    ## 1067        1 1.313987e+18
    ## 1068        0 1.313987e+18
    ## 1069        0 1.515916e+18
    ## 1070        0 1.515916e+18
```

Answer (score 1):

An R-base way:

```
options(scipen = 999)
df[!df$Brand_ID %in% 0L:6L, ]$User_ID <- df[!df$Brand_ID %in% 0L:6L, ]$Brand_ID
df[!df$Brand_ID %in% 0L:6L, ]$Brand_ID <- NA
```